# 4 input sequence detector

Tags: digital-logic, design, detection

I need to design a 4-input sequence detector and I'm really having trouble with this.

The numbers are entered as a 4 digit input (0010 is 2, 0110 is 6, etc).

The sequence must detect, for instance, a 5 digit key (i.e 3-4-1-7-5)

I'm really troubled with the design methodology for this problem, because if we do it the traditional way, it's going to take forever, we need 3 state variables and 11 different inputs possibilities to deal with (the 1010 key is "clear")

If we type 3-4-4, the sequence must clear, for example.

If we type 3-4-1-7-5 (the correct sequence), then the output should be a logical 1.

Otherwise, the output is zero.

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the sequential circuit is synchronous (has an external clock source)

Comment: This is just to draw the schematic of the sequential circuit.

I've tried using flip-flops, but I couldn't get the sequence to clear properly, and the way I was trying is just guessing and checking, which is bad.

Comment: Why don't you try drawing a state diagram, like a flowchart? I think you'll see that the problem isn't as hard as you think.

Comment: I have, as I've stated in my question. It's quite a simple state diagram.

But there are ELEVEN different input possibilities (remember there are four inputs, and not one). Each of these will lead to a different state, which is associated to three state variables.

This method will be too troublesome, and I'm looking for a simpler way, given the simplicity of the state diagram.

I'd appreciate it if you could assist with the state diagram --> circuit transition

Comment: Why not use a counter and a LUT for the current valid input, and clear if not valid?

Comment: Can we assume that you have some sort of clock or strobe signal (suitably debounced) that indicates when a state change should occur?

Comment: Sorry, your original question didn't say anything about a state diagram. Suppose you had a blob of combinational logic that would tell you whether the input was equal to 3, and another blob to tell you if the input was equal to 4, and so on. If you use the outputs from these blobs in your state transitions would that simplify the diagram?

Comment: Yes, it's a clocked sequential circuit.

Comment: @joehass, sorry, for somereason I thought I had stated that. State diagram is what I meant by "traditional way".

But Im fine with the state diagram, it is pretty easy. I'm interested in how I can design a circuit form it.

Comment: Hint: think about how you could do this with a one-hot encoding.

Comment: Not sure what the point of automatically resetting the sequence would be. If the idea is let the user just keep going until the right sequence is hit, the device isn't as secure as it could be, b/c the sliding window effectively lets an unauthorized user try more than 1 string per key press. And if the user hits a wrong key, you don't want to notify them right away, you want to take the entire five (or whatever) characters before Sounding the Obnoxious Buzzer. Otherwise you're instructing them on what digit they got wrong and they'll crack it in a few dozen tries at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: The states in your state machine are not associated with the binary codes representing the key inputs, they're associated with the number of correct numbers entered so far. You start out in an initial, or "reset" state, in which no valid keys have been entered so far, and then proceed to states representing 1 valid key entered, 2 valid keys entered, etc. until you get to the final state with 5 valid keys entered. In the last state, the output is 1; in all others it's 0.

In each state, if the next valid key is entered, you proceed to the next state; otherwise, you go back to the initial state.

Comment: but they have to be associated with which key is pressed, and in what state.

Otherwise I can just press the right keys in the wrong order and it is going to work. 

Sorry, but I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: @triplebig: Only one key will advance to the next state. Any other will clear.

Comment: Say you make it really simple so that you have ST0 -> ST5. In ST0 if you see the correct bit pattern on the 4-bit keyed input you then transition to ST1. The logic for that transition equation is a simple 7 input AND gate (three inputs represent the ST bits and 4 inputs represent the KEY bits. Some inputs may need inverters to feed the AND for those signals that are zero at the transition time. Then just repeat this four more times for S1 + 2nd KEY input and so forth.

Comment: This advice should work fine for any sequence. Why should repetitions matter? Let S0 be the 'reset' state. Let the magic sequence be 2-2-2-2. A '2' entry takes S0 to S1. A second '2' takes state S1 to state S2. Etc. However many digits you want. It's the *transitions* that match up to key entries, not the states. When you get all the digits, *that* state sets the output to unlock the lock or whatever. Now the real problem, of course, will be *key bounce*.

Comment: @trav1s: You seem to be hung up on this point. The OP has stated that if an incorrect sequence is entered, you must start over. Your fancy sliding-window sequence matcher is completely unnecessary.

Comment: ok, so I was assuming a clean reset, probably owing to the OP's statement of 'the 1010 key is "clear"'. Perhaps if the OP has a sliding window requirement *and* a clear key, the OP should reconsider the requirements.

Comment: @JustJeff Oh! I forgot about the clear key! Yes, the clear key also avoids the problems I described, if the user uses it after making a mistake.

Comment: @DaveTweed, sorry about that, bear with me while I remove any erroneous comments I made because I neglected the clear key.

Answer (score 3):

### Presenting the SuperShifting©, Flexi-Coded MultiDetector™:

---

One way we can solve the problem is with a shift register which stores the last 5 input codes. We also have a register which stores the passcode. Then we use digital comparators (logic AND of bitwise XOR) to see if each input code matches the corresponding passcode. If they all match, the output is 1. Otherwise, the output is 0. Here's a full schematic:

[image]

**Featuring:**

- Changeable passcode
- Number of digits is easily scalable
- Bits per digit is easily scalable
- Avoids the need for a clear key
- Vulnerable to rainbow table attacks

Because of the vulnerability to rainbow table attacks *feature*, if you forget your passcode, you can gain it back with increased speed by compressing your key guesses in a rainbow table attack! いいね.

Comment: It's also vulnerable to a "rainbow string" attack.

Comment: Of course, the advantage with this is that one doesn't have to regenerate the state transition table and propagate it into the device, just to change the pass code. And at the cost of one more bit line through the registers, or a small auxiliary counter (not much more than this, however you slice it, left as exercise to the reader) you can make it stop accepting input after the 5th character and thwart the dreaded rainbow string. So +1